# When would a Singleton not work as a Singleton?

Tags: java, singleton

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [cracking singleton with other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654876/cracking-singleton-with-other-ways)

Can anyone please tell me when a `Singleton` would not work as a `Singleton`?

Comment: That would be when it is not written correctly. Do you have a specific example you would like an explanation about?

Comment: A singleton would not work as a singleton the moment you create two instances of it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question?

Comment: A singleton won't be a singleton if it does not work as a Singleton. :)

Comment: Singletons in Java can be implemented in different ways. Add details about exactly what implementation you are referring to.

Comment: This one was asked a few hours ago: [Cracking Singleton with Other Ways](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11654876/697630).

Comment: Reminds of the old joke... Q: When is a door not a door? A: When its ajar. ;)

Answer (score 10):

There is very good post published on [Sun](http://oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/singleton-1577166.html) website by author **Joshua Fox**. Please go through this.

below are some of them scenario when your `Singleton` doesn't behave like.

1. Multiple Singletons in Two or More Virtual Machines
2. Multiple Singletons Simultaneously Loaded by Different Class Loaders
3. Singleton Classes Destroyed by Garbage Collection, then Reloaded
4. Purposely Reloaded Singleton Classes
5. Copies of a Singleton Object that has Undergone Serialization and Deserialization

Comment: The link given by @amicngh appears to have changed since Oracle took ownership of Java. I believe the new link is http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/singleton-1577166.html

Answer (score 3):

A singleton (in Java land) wouldn't work as a singleton if a given class is loaded by multiple class-loaders. Since a single class can exist (or can be loaded) in multiple classloaders, it's quite possible to have "multiple" instances of a "supposedly" singleton class for a given JVM instance. But this is a pretty rare case and doesn't happen a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to create more than one instance of the class then it doesn't remain singleton by using ways like cloning, De-serialization etc.