# Singleton not behaving as a singleton

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

In many interview I have faced a question

```
When a singleton class not behave as singleton
```

Can you please let me it little bit more details?

Comment: Your interview question is probably related to thread-unsafe singletons. There's plenty of documentation about that.

Comment: I also felt the same as Mena.

Comment: [When would a Singleton not work as a Singleton?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664076/when-would-a-singleton-not-work-as-a-singleton) & [cracking singleton with other ways](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654876/cracking-singleton-with-other-ways)