# Regarding changing the constructor specifier from private to protected of singleton

Tags: java, design-patterns

What would happen if we change the constructor of the singleton from private to protected? How we can prevent it breaking in that case?

Singleton:

```
public class SingletonObject
{
    private static SingletonObject ref;

    private SingletonObject () //private constructor
    {
        System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
    }

    public  static synchronized   SingletonObject getSingletonObject()
    {
        if (ref == null)
            ref = new SingletonObject();
                return ref;
    }   

    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException
    {
        throw new CloneNotSupportedException ();
    }

}
```

For breaking the singleton the following url contains the required info [cracking singleton with other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654876/cracking-singleton-with-other-ways#comment15443658_11654876).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Joshua Bloch's Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683) on Singletons Properties:

> The private constructor is called only once, to initialize the public
>   static final field (...). The lack of public or protected
>   constructors guarantees a “*monoinstance*” universe: Exactly one (...)
>   instance will exist once the *Singleton* class is initialized—no more, no
>   less. Nothing that a client does can change this.

So, if you make your Singleton Constructor protected you're exposing your Constructor to let any class in the same package to make instances an instance of `SingletonObject`. If that happens, your Singleton Pattern is broken.

Relaxing the access modifiers of the constructor on any way -making it protected, public or default- is an open gate to instance generation, and that's not desired in a Singleton implementation.

Comment: A subclass can only instantiate the "singleton" class if it is in the same package. However, a subclass in a different package *can* be instantiated itself.

Comment: Wasn't aware of that. Answer fixed xD

Answer (score 1):

Simple: Changing the constructor access modifier from `private` to `protected` allows any class in the same package to instantiate `SingletonObject`. We can easily create a class "in the same package" by specifying the corresponding `package` statement.

**Edit:** The answer of Carlos made me realize an additional problem that results from making the constructor `protected` as opposed to `public`: A subclass of the singleton class can be created (in another package), which can be freely instantiated and have its instance methods called; the singleton class itself no longer has full control over where and how instances (or 1 instance) are created.

Comment: so you mean to say then in that case the law of singleton would be get break and it would no more be singleton, could you please post the code so that understanding will be clear.

Comment: @UmNyobe please explain in detail as i have not understood completely.

Comment: If `SingletonObject` is in package `xyz`, we can create another class in package `xyz` which can then create as many instances of `SingletonObject` as it desires. Thus, with a `protected` constructor, `SingletonObject` can no longer ensure there is only 1 instance at any time.

Comment: Protected exposes the constructor to sub-classes, not to Classes in the same package.

Comment: Actually, it does. Try it out. As I commented on your answer above, a subclass cannot instantiate the class if not in the same package. However, since the subclass itself may be instantiated, that can be considered breakage of the singleton as well.